# Eclipse cdt: IFile/IPath to IDocument

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Is it possible to retrieve an IDocument from an IFile or IPath? I have tried this:

```
IFile file = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile(hFilePath);
TextFileDocumentProvider provider = new TextFileDocumentProvider();
IDocument doc = provider.getDocument(file);
```

but getDocument seems to return null.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue and I found a post [here](http://eclipse.1072660.n5.nabble.com/how-to-get-the-IDocument-of-an-ITextFileBuffer-created-from-an-IFile-td59106.html) that helped. Give this a shot:

```
IDocumentProvider provider = new TextFileDocumentProvider();
provider.connect(ifile);
document = provider.getDocument(ifile);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not the right kind of argument for getDocument(), but you should instead be using the headless FileBuffers APIs, starting from FileBuffers itself, getting the ITextFileBufferManager, and then using it to open a text file buffer and its IDocument: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/filebuffers/FileBuffers.html .

Don't forget to disconnect from the file buffer when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
IFile file = (IFile) resource;
IPath filePath = file.getLocation();
filePath = FileBuffers.normalizeLocation(filePath);
IDocument document = FileBuffers.getTextFileBufferManager().getTextFileBuffer(filePath , LocationKind.NORMALIZE).getDocument();
```